# Behavior while chasis clustering between SRX650

Tags: juniper-srx, switch

Assume I need ping from R1 to R2.

SRX1 is Primary. All necessary zones,security policies are assigned. Also two interfaces are placed into different routing-instances called VR1 and VR2.

Here the ping command from R1 to R2 will allow ! IS NOT IT ?

If SRX1  become disable, then SRX2 become primary. In that case traffic must follow via trunk between of switches (Ex2200).

Am I right ???

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't understand what this means: *"Here the ping command from R1 to R2 will allow ! IS NOT IT ?"*  Can you please be more explicit about this issue?

Comment: this question I wanted to clarify. Having such a scheme possible to get an reply from R2 when sending icmp packets from R1. I believe that it is possible! But suddenly have any comments from you?

Comment: I would like to know what settings to two switches (ex2200) is necessary to achieve redundancy between srx650?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are at least partially right.  For HA failover, you'll need the same ports to have access to the same VLANs.  You'll need to trunk VLANs 172 and 192 between your two EX2200 switches and you'll need to make sure both VLANs are available to SRX-1 and SRX-2.

For pings from R1 to R2, it sounds like you're trying to use VRFs which should actually keep them from talking to each other.  If you want them to talk, they should be in the same routing instance.

Comment: Hello! concerning the same routing instances. Really, there will be some routing-instances and all necessary routes will be imported from others.summing up. Do you think that such a scheme is the place to be?

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't know what you're asking here.

Comment: everything is fine! Already figured out!